# How to stop dropdownlists where autopostback true, from posting to a new page set in postbackurl of button ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

The page performs as intended locally, the problem is when I upload to windows server and access it from there.

I have 2 to 3 dropdownlists displayed (depending on whats selected in the first dropdownlist)....

The first 2 dropdownlists where autopostback is set to true, will autopostback to the same page (intended performance). However, after I click the button within the form, and go back to original page, whenever there is a selectedindexchanged event on those dropdownlists, those dropdownlists are not autopostback to the same page anymore, they will now post to the postbackurl declared in the button (this is unintended and not the desired results)

How can I get those dropdownlists to stop from posting to new page on selectedindexchanged after I click the button and go back to original page?

Again, the dropdownlists do not autopostback to a new page until I click the button and then go back to that original page. At that point they then post to the postbackurl that is declared in the button. I don't understand why this is happening.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div style="text-align: center">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="toolGroupDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="toolgroupddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="sizeDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="False">
            </asp:DropDownList>

            <asp:DropDownList ID="attDropDown" runat="server" Visible="False">
            </asp:DropDownList><br />

            <asp:Button ID="seeToolsButton" runat="server" Text="See Tools" Visible="False" PostBackUrl="/products" />
        </form>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is some code-behind, not sure if this is relevant though...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Testing
{
    public partial class WebForm12 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string listing;
        public string attsize;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                FillDropDown();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("postback occured");              
            }   
        }

        protected void toolgroupddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listing = toolGroupDropDown.SelectedValue;           
            sizeDropDown.DataSource = this.GetSizeRecords();
            sizeDropDown.DataTextField = "groups";
            sizeDropDown.DataValueField = "groups";         
            sizeDropDown.DataBind();         
            sizeDropDown.Visible = true;
            seeToolsButton.Visible = true;
            toolGroupDropDown.Items.Remove(toolGroupDropDown.Items.FindByValue(""));

            if (toolGroupDropDown.SelectedValue != "END")
            {
                sizeDropDown.AutoPostBack = false;
                attDropDown.Visible = false;
                sizeDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose Your Size", ""));
            }
            else
            {
                attDropDown.Visible = true;
                sizeDropDown.AutoPostBack = true;
                sizeDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Choose Your Size", ""));
            }
        }

        protected void sizeddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (toolGroupDropDown.SelectedValue == "END")
            {
                attDropDown.DataSource = this.GetAtts(attsize);
                attDropDown.DataTextField = "NoOfAtts";
                attDropDown.DataValueField = "NoOfAtts";
                attDropDown.DataBind();

                attDropDown.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                attDropDown.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I only posted the code-behind that seemed relevant. Nothing else in the code relates to the question at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is page changing the *action* attribute. At Html level, initially you have:

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="./WebForm12">
```

So dropdowns correctly post back to WebForm12. But when you press the button.

```
<asp:Button ID="seeToolsButton" runat="server" PostBackUrl="/products" />
```

The page does two things using Javascript:

- Change the action attribute of the form to "/products".
- Post the form.

When you navigate back in your browser, the form looks like this

```
<form method="post" id="form1" action="/products">
```

But now, dropdowns will post the form to /products, not WebForm12.

**Solution:** One way to fix that is adding this script to your aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onpageshow = function () {
        form1.action = "./<%=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)%>";
    };
</script>
```

However if your browser does not support *onpageshow* (e.g. IE10 or older), then you'd rather attach the function to click event of the dropdowns.